# Closed form for sum of a simple power law series

Tags: summation, geometric-series

I'm struggling to find a closed form for $g_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{k^2}10^{-2dk}i^kj^k$ where $i, j, d, k, N$ are constant natural numbers. This, of course, isn't a geometric series due to the power law term $\frac{1}{k^2}$ at the beginning (if it were, I'd just use the finite geometric sum formula), so I'm not sure how to proceed, but it seems reasonably simple, so I wonder if it has a closed form.

Comment: Presumably, $d$ is also an integer? Ther is unlikely to be a closed form.

Comment: Why are you so sure this sum has a closed form?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28from+1+to+n-1%29+%28a%5Ek%2Fk%5E2%29

Comment: Well, it doesn't have a closed form.

Comment: This sum is of the form $$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{x^k}{k^2},$$ where $x=ij/10^{2d},$ but this is unlikely to have a closed form.

Comment: Wait, it seems @MariusS.L.'s comment DOES give a closed form (involving the Lerch transcendent and polylogarithm) for a sum of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{x^k}{k^2}$.

Comment: Formulas involving those functions are usually not considered closed.

Comment: Since this is for a programming project where I can use a library to call the Lerch and polylog functions, this suffices for my needs, thanks. Should I leave this question open?

Comment: You can write the infinite sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^2}=-\int_0^{x}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt,$$ when $|x|<1,$ But that is probably not helpful - I doubt the integral has a good closed form, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=10^{-d}ij$. So $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{x^k}{k^2}$.   and $f'(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}$.  So (using $xf'(x))$ $f'(x)+xf''(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1}x^{k-1}=\frac{1-x^{N-1}}{1-x}$.

Solve diff. equation to get $f(x)$.

Comment: Solving the differential equation on Mathematica gives a complicated expression involving the hypergeometric function and an integral so I'll probably use the Lerch approach, but thank you, this is very clever!

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the differential equation $$f'(x)+xf''(x)=\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}$$ is not bad
$$f(x)=\text{Li}_2(x)+c_1 \log (x)+c_2-x^{n+1} \Phi (x,2,n+1)-\frac{x^n}{n^2}$$ where $\Phi(.)$  is the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function which is available in many scientific libraries.

You could be interested by this very recent [document](https://fredrikj.net/blog/2022/02/computing-the-lerch-transcendent/).